# Glashfish exception with JSF application

Tags: class, glassfish, loader

I try to run my application in glassfish appli application server.But i got struck.The server log denotes the follwing error message,How can i resolve this?

```
[#|2010-07-14T17:53:54.152+0800|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading|_ThreadID=38;_ThreadName=Thread-396;_RequestID=cde2a094-d34e-4e64-bb22-93a3656caba5;|Input stream has been finalized or forced closed without being explicitly closed; stream instantiation reported in following stack trace
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader$SentinelInputStream.<init>(EJBClassLoader.java:1166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader$InternalJarURLConnection.getInputStream(EJBClassLoader.java:1259)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(EJBClassLoader.java:796)
    at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2030)
    at cryptix.CryptixProperties.setProperties(CryptixProperties.java:504)
    at cryptix.CryptixProperties.<clinit>(CryptixProperties.java:414)
    at cryptix.provider.Cryptix.getVersionAsDouble(Cryptix.java:115)
    at cryptix.provider.Cryptix.<init>(Cryptix.java:93)
    at com.infomindz.commons.utils.security.EncryptionUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.bll.systemmanagement.LicenseBean.generatePrivateKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.bll.systemmanagement.LicenseBean.getLicenseDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.bll.systemmanagement.LicenseBean.validateLicense(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:83)
    at $Proxy837.validateLicense(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.bll.usermanagement.UserBean.authenticateAndLogin(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.bll.usermanagement.UserBean.login(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:83)
    at $Proxy827.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.bll.services.PlatformFacadeBean.login(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:83)
    at $Proxy944.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.pl.services.PlatformDelegate.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.infomindz.platform.pl.usermanagement.Login.loginButtonAction(Login.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
    at com.infomindz.platform.pl.listeners.ExceptionHandlingActionListener.processAction(ExceptionHandlingActionListener.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
    at com.infomindz.platform.pl.CustomFacesServlet.service(CustomFacesServlet.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.infomindz.platform.pl.listeners.SSCMSSessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(SSCMSSessionExpiryFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.process(SSLReadTask.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.doTask(SSLReadTask.java:228)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

When i have google it for resolve this issue i got one link related to this i have enclosed it here for your reference.

https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-1820?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs

Any help regarding this should be appreicate.

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the source in Cryptix and it looks like your properties file doesn't exist. This might be an older version, but they're swallowing the exception.

Do you see another callstack in your logs?

```
try {  
    BufferedInputStream in =  
    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pf));  
    properties.load(in);  
    in.close();  
    lib_path = path;  
    loaded = true;  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```